# How can ı use GEOADD in Python ? (Redis)

Tags: python, redis

I want the store geospatial information in Redis.
I am executing the following code

```
from redis import Redis

redis_con = Redis(host="localhost", port=6379)
redis_con.geoadd("Sicily", 13.361389, 38.115556, "Palermo")
```

But ı got error like that

```
raise DataError("GEOADD allows either 'nx' or 'xx', not both")

redis.exceptions.DataError: GEOADD allows either 'nx' or 'xx', not both
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work for you:

```
from redis import Redis

redis_con = Redis(host="localhost", port=6379)
coords = (13.361389, 38.115556, "Palermo")
redis_con.geoadd("Sicily", coords)
```

The signature for [`geoadd`](https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/commands.html?highlight=geoadd#redis.commands.core.CoreCommands.geoadd) is:

```
geoadd(name, values, nx=False, xx=False, ch=False)
    name: Union[bytes, str, memoryview]
    values: Sequence[Union[bytes, memoryview, str, int, float]]
    nx (bool, default: False)
    xx (bool, default: False)
    ch (bool, default: False)
```

You need to specify your coordinates as a sequence like a `list` or `tuple`, because right now you're specifying arguments so that the method thinks you've specified `nx`, `xx`, and `ch`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Where is my head. How can I not see that